# Comments turned off, but 'Leave a reply' link still there

Tags: comments

On my site, commenting is not enabled.

But at the top of each blog post (except for one, strangely), there's a 'Leave a reply' link.

(the link doesn't do anything -- but the words 'leave a reply' sitting there obviously make it look like you can leave a reply...)

I don't see any 'discussion module' in my edit-post page.

Here's an example page with a 'Leave a reply' link, just under the post title:

http://richardclunan.com/blog/i-bet-these-12-questions-can-help-you-sell-more-helpful-copywriting-ideas/

I'm on Mac Chrome -- in case it's a small browser-related bug...

Comment: What **Theme** are you using? Please post relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have forgotten to wrap the `comments_popup_link()` with `if ( comments_open() )`

```
if ( comments_open() ) :
  comments_popup_link( [...] );
endif;
```